# How can I queue a function to be executed in a Qt application's main thread with as high priority as possible?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I would like to be able to have a separate thread queue a `std::function` to be executed in a Qt application's main thread with as high a priority as possible, meaning that executing this function takes precedence over anything else that is happening in the main thread, save for any task the main thread is currently executing. (To clarify, the currently executing task in the main thread doesn't need to yield execution or anything like that. This queued function should simply be the very next event that the thread processes with as little delay as possible.)

There are a number of ways a thread can set up a function to be called in another specific `QThread`, such as using a single shot `QTimer` with a zero second interval, or using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. But I'm not sure how execution of the function will be prioritized in relation to other tasks that are being processed by the main thread.

The first thought I had was to create a custom `QEvent` that contains an instance of the function I want to execute, write a handler for the new custom event type that executes the function, and then post it using something like:

```
qApp->postEvent(qApp, customEvent, Qt::HighEventPriority * 1000000);
```

...or using some other suitable huge integer for the event priority. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this since I don't have deep knowledge of how Qt's event system works. (Like how would this be prioritized in relation to events dispatched to other `QObject`'s whose thread affinity is set to the main thread?)

Is there a better method?

Comment: If you don't want to subclass `QApplication` (and I agree, you probably don't want to unless absolutely neccessary), check out `QObject::installEventFilter(QObject *)`.  You can call `qApp->installEventFilter(whateverObjectYouWant)` so that your `whateverObjectYouWant` object has its `eventFilter()` method called when the `QApplication` object receives your high-priority event.  See:  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter

Comment: Regarding the event priority: The Qt docs say that events are always delivered in order of descending priority, so if you set your priority to `INT_MAX` your event should be guaranteed to be the first to be delivered once the main thread returns to the event loop.

Comment: Overall, it's best to design so that tbe GUI input queue is never overloaded anyway:)

Comment: Sounds strange... Be note that main thread is a GUI thread. What kind of task you need to execute avoiding the event queue?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Even though I use event filters all the time, I had a brain fart and didn't think of using them in this situation. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @VladimirBershov I need to have worker threads use macOS-specific functions that are only allowed to be called from an app's main thread. I need the tasks being executed by these worker threads to complete as efficiently as possible, hence needing the high priority events.

Comment: I think you may be asking the wrong question, a.k.a. known as "XY problem". In particular, it would be clearer if you described what you want to achieve and why you think that the behaviour you describe solves this problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I feel like with each passing day it gets harder not to ask an "XY problem" on stackoverflow! The truth is that what I'm trying to do is an immensely complex process that's part of a proprietary application, so a) it's unreasonable for me to go into description of everything I'm trying to do, and b) I can't share any code anyway. But the gist of it is that I wrote a large amount of code that uses Apple's Accessibility API in a separate thread, and now I need to have that thread offload those API calls to the main thread with as little added latency as possible.

Comment: @GuyGizmo For your part, you are right, you can ask a specific question and not discuss other details. When people have a ready answer, they don't ask what your project is doing. But do not forget that for yourself you must know the answer to the question, what problem and why you are solving. Also note: Software's Primary Technical Imperative: Managing Complexity. You don't have to keep the entire project in mind to solve a single problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I settled on:

```
#define kFunctionEventType ((QEvent::Type)(QEvent::User + 1))

class FunctionEvent : public QEvent {
public:
    FunctionEvent(const std::function<void()> &inFunc) : QEvent(kFunctionEventType), func(inFunc){};
    std::function<void()> func;
};

class FunctionEventReceiver : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FunctionEventReceiver() : QObject(nullptr) {};
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event);
};

static FunctionEventReceiver * functionEventReceiver()
{
    static FunctionEventReceiver receiver;
    return &receiver;
}

bool FunctionEventReceiver::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() != kFunctionEventType) {
        return QObject::event(event);
    }
    
    FunctionEvent *functionEvent = (FunctionEvent *)event;
    functionEvent->func();
    functionEvent->accept();
    
    return true;
}

void executeInMainThreadWithMaximumPriority(const std::function<void ()> &func)
{
    FunctionEvent *event = new FunctionEvent(func);
    qApp->postEvent(functionEventReceiver(), event, INT_MAX);
}

void initialize()
{
    // Ensures receiver is created in main thread:
    functionEventReceiver();
}
```

The one caveat is that I must call `initialize()` at the start of my app to ensure that the event receiver is created and associated with the application's main thread.